# How to set text alignment line by line in TextEdit?

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

I'm writing an app using qml, and text messages have bi direction languages too.
I want to each line starts with appropriate alignment like below image.
I know i can split lines and set direction but i want to know if here is a better solution, because the QTextEdit handle this itself.

[image]

Comment: Why not create several TextEdits?

Comment: @eyllanesc, I want to know qml TextEdit doesn't have this feature ?

Comment: It does not have that feature, you can only set an alignment for all TextEdit text, not row, maybe with HTML. But I have a question, how do you identify which row should be aligned to the right or to the left?

Comment: @eyllanesc, lines that starts with Persian characters are right aligned and English left aligned.

Comment: Do you have an algorithm that already allows to discriminate between both types of characters?

Comment: @eyllanesc, yes. a solution is, split text by \n and then set dir property on each line and then add <br/> tag between each line and set html to textedit.